# Can't get drop down menu to display in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, doctype, html-components

I am using pre-built CSS and HTML to display a drop down menu on my site, but the menu does not work in Internet Explorer. I am not sure if it is the doctype or what, I have it linked to a csshover.htc page, as it came with, but it still won't work. I will list the code below for the first section of the menu that contains the doctype and file link, as well as the csshover.htc code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  

<title>Mega Drop Down Menu</title>  
<!--[if IE 6]>  
<style>  
body {behavior: url("csshover.htc");}  
#menu li .drop {background:url("img/drop.gif") no-repeat right 8px;   
</style>  
<![endif]-->  

<body>

<ul id="menu">

 <li><a href="#" class="drop">Home</a><!-- Begin Home Item -->

    <div class="dropdown_2columns"><!-- Begin 2 columns container -->

        <div class="col_2">
            <h2>Welcome !</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col_2">
            <p></p>             

        </div>



    </div><!-- End 2 columns container -->
```

And here is the info from the csshover.htc file:

```
<public:attach event="ondocumentready" onevent="CSSHover()" />
<script>

window.CSSHover=(function(){var m=/(^|\s)((([^a]([^ ]+)?)|(a([^#.][^ ]+)+)):            (hover|active|focus))/i;var n=/(.*?)\:(hover|active|focus)/i;var o=/[^:]+:([a-z\-    ]+).*/i;var p=/(\.([a-z0-9_\-]+):[a-z]+)|(:[a-z]+)/gi;var q=/\.([a-z0-9_\-]*on(hover|active|focus))/i;var s=/msie (5|6|7)/i;var t=/backcompat/i;var u={index:0,list:['text-kashida','text-kashida-space','text-justify'],get:function(){return this.list[(this.index++)%this.list.length]}};var v=function(c){return c.replace(/-(.)/mg,function(a,b){return b.toUpperCase()})};var w={elements:[],callbacks:{},init:function(){if(!s.test(navigator.userAgent)&&!t.test(window.document.compatMode)){return}var a=window.document.styleSheets,l=a.length;for(var i=0;i<l;i++){this.parseStylesheet(a[i])}},parseStylesheet:function(a){if(a.imports){try{var b=a.imports;var l=b.length;for(var i=0;i<l;i++){this.parseStylesheet(a.imports[i])}}catch(securityException){}}try{var c=a.rules;var r=c.length;for(var j=0;j<r;j++){this.parseCSSRule(c[j],a)}}catch(someException){}},parseCSSRule:function(a,b){var c=a.selectorText;if(m.test(c)){var d=a.style.cssText;var e=n.exec(c)[1];var f=c.replace(o,'on$1');var g=c.replace(p,'.$2'+f);var h=q.exec(g)[1];var i=e+h;if(!this.callbacks[i]){var j=u.get();var k=v(j);b.addRule(e,j+':expression(CSSHover(this, "'+f+'", "'+h+'", "'+k+'"))');this.callbacks[i]=true}b.addRule(g,d)}},patch:function(a,b,c,d){try{var f=a.parentNode.currentStyle[d];a.style[d]=f}catch(e){a.runtimeStyle[d]=''}if(!a.csshover){a.csshover=[]}if(!a.csshover[c]){a.csshover[c]=true;var g=new CSSHoverElement(a,b,c);this.elements.push(g)}return b},unload:function(){try{var l=this.elements.length;for(var i=0;i<l;i++){this.elements[i].unload()}this.elements=[];this.callbacks={}}catch(e){}}};var x={onhover:{activator:'onmouseenter',deactivator:'onmouseleave'},onactive:{activator:'onmousedown',deactivator:'onmouseup'},onfocus:{activator:'onfocus',deactivator:'onblur'}};function CSSHoverElement(a,b,c){this.node=a;this.type=b;var d=new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+c+'(\\s|$)','g');this.activator=function(){a.className+=' '+c};this.deactivator=function(){a.className=a.className.replace(d,' ')};a.attachEvent(x[b].activator,this.activator);a.attachEvent(x[b].deactivator,this.deactivator)}CSSHoverElement.prototype={unload:function(){this.node.detachEvent(x[this.type].activator,this.activator);this.node.detachEvent(x[this.type].deactivator,this.deactivator);this.activator=null;this.deactivator=null;this.node=null;this.type=null}};window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload',function(){w.unload()});return function(a,b,c,d){if(a){return w.patch(a,b,c,d)}else{w.init()}}})();
```

Comment: Well you're missing an `<html>` element for starters ..

Comment: We might want to see the contents of `menu.css`, too... also, which version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Change over to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

and add 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`

into your head
also add a `<html>` tag and `</head>` tag
for example

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Your missing a lot of tags which are essential add these in and im sure your problem should be fixed

you also aren't closing your `<ul>` tag and `<li>` tag